# jquery droppable/html5 api - how to make element droppable and draggable

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

i know how to make an emelent that is draggable and can be dropped at some dropzone but how can I make this droppable element draggable also in another dropzone? So lets image I have a container that is droppable and here I can move elements around (vertically lets say) and additionaly i can drop some element into these daggable elements and move them around inside em. Is it possble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a class as a container where you draggable and/or sortable `div` element can be sorted or dropped.

You then can duplicate that class, for example class `dropzone`. This way the element can be dragged from the one div to the other, and you can sort them.

**snippet:**

```js
$(".colzone").sortable({
  connectWith: ".colzone",
  update: function(event, ui) {},
  placeholder: "dashed2"
});

$(".dropzone").sortable({
  connectWith: ".dropzone",
  update: function(event, ui) {},
  placeholder: "dashed"
});
```

```css
.colzone {
  margin: 10px;
  border: green 2px solid;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.colpick {
  background-color: orange;
  border: yellow 2px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropzone {
  margin: 10px;
  border: red 2px solid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: #ededed;
}

.grid-users {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  cursor: move;
  border: #000 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dashed {
  border: 2px dashed #999;
  background: #ede8e8;
  height: 35px;
}

.dashed2 {
  border: 2px dashed #999;
  background: #ede8e8;
  height: 295px;
  width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="colzone row">

    <!-- COLUMN 1 -->
    <div class="colpick">
      <div style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
        COLUMN 1
      </div>
      <div class="dropzone">
        <div id="team-1" class="grid-users">TEAM 1</div>
        <div id="team-2" class="grid-users">TEAM 2</div>
        <div id="team-3" class="grid-users">TEAM 3</div>
        <div id="team-4" class="grid-users">TEAM 4</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- COLUMN 2 -->
    <div class="colpick">
      <div style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
        COLUMN 2
      </div>
      <div class="dropzone">
        <div id="team-5" class="grid-users">TEAM 5</div>
        <div id="team-6" class="grid-users">TEAM 6</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- COLUMN 3 -->
    <div class="colpick">
      <div style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
        COLUMN 3
      </div>
      <div class="dropzone"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the effort but I would like to move these dropzones (2 columns) aswell inside another dropzone so i can sort columns in a container and items inside each column too.

Comment: Updated and added a third column

Comment: so right now i can move team boxes around but what if I would like to move whole column 1 to the right? so it would be column2 | column1 | column3. Thats the result im aiming for. It means i can move the whole coumn only between columns and items between columns and in each column aswekk. Can it be done by sortable?

Comment: Sure, now you can sort Column 1, 2 and 3. And you can drag/sort all the team divs around in the three columns